# How is it possible that std::shared_ptr<Derived> casts to std::shared_ptr<Base> with no compiler errors?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, derived-class

I'm trying to implement a custom smart pointer. So I have something like this:

```
// Base class for every object
class Base {
public:
    int n_holders {};
};

class Derived : public Base {};

// Custom shared pointer
template<class T>
class Sptr {
public:
    T* obj;
    Sptr(T* obj_) : obj{obj_} {}
};

void SomeFunc(Sptr<Base> obj) {}

void SomeFunc2(std::shared_ptr<Base> obj) {}

int main()
{
    auto a = Sptr<Base>(new Base());
    SomeFunc(a); // OK

    auto b = Sptr<Derived>(new Derived());
    SomeFunc(b); // Error. No matching function call to SomeFunc

    auto c = std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Base());
    SomeFunc2(c); // OK

    auto d = std::shared_ptr<Derived>(new Derived());
    SomeFunc2(d); // OK !!!
}
```

My question is why compiler can't automatically cast from `Sptr<Derived>` to `Sptr<Base>` if using `std::shared_ptr` there is no errors?. How to make it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` has a constructor (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)):

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r ) noexcept;  (9)
```

This overload ...

> Constructs a shared_ptr which shares ownership of the object managed
> by r. If r manages no object, *this manages no object too. The
> template overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if Y* is
> not implicitly convertible to (until C++17)compatible with (since
> C++17) T*.

Hence, in some sense the tricky part is not to convert the shared pointer, but to prevent it when the pointer types are not implicitly convertible. You can use SFINAE to achieve that.

Here is a toy example that has conversions from `Bar<T1>` to `Bar<T2>` (but not the other way around) enabled only when `T1` inherits from `T2`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T1>
struct Bar {
    Bar() {}

    template <typename T2, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T1,T2>,int> = 0>
    Bar(Bar<T2>){} 

};

struct Foo {};
struct Derived : Foo {};

int main(){
    Bar<Derived> d;
    Bar<Foo> b;
    //d = b; // eror
    b = d;  // OK
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nao1zK)

You probably want it more general, like shared pointer, to allow such conversion whenever a `T2*` can be converted to a `T1*`, not only when they inherit from each other (see [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible), I have to admit, I don't really understand the change that came with C++17, so I can only guess: maybe its [`std::is_layout_compatible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_layout_compatible) in that case). So to mimic a pre-C++17 smart pointer you could use:

```
    template <typename T2, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T2*,T1*>,int> = 0>
    Bar(Bar<T2>){}
```

which enables the conversion for all `T2` where `T2*` can be converted to a `T1*`.

Comment: Or if C++20 constraints can be used, `template <typename T2> requires std::is_base_of_v<T1, T2> Bar(Bar<T2>);` or similar with `is_convertible_v`.

Comment: prefer `std::enable_if_t<cond, int> = 0` over `typename = std::enable_if_t<cond>`. Former allows overloads, and cannot be hackjacked in general case (and constructor is an exception  :-) )

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818. So I should implement copy constructor `template <typename T2, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of_v<T1,T2>>::type> Sptr(const Sptr<T2>& otherSptr)`, right?

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов no thats not what I wrote. You should implement a conversion constructor that only particiaptes in overload resolution for the conversions you want to enable. Conversions between derived and base is only one case  and my code was just to give rough idea of how this can be done. Replace the condition with the condition you want to have

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Ok. I get it. So if all my classes derived from some base class `Obj` which contain counter then I should write `template <typename T2, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Obj,T2>,int> = 0>`, right?

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов no, because then you can only use your `Sptr` only with object that inherit from `Obj` and if that is the case you do not need that SFINAE check in the first place. I am really sorry, but I don't know what to add to the answer, I'll give it a try...

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 `you can only use your Sptr only with object that inherit from Obj` - this is definetely what I need.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов in that case I misunderstood what you actually want to achieve, because then your `Sptr` does not mimic a `std::smart_ptr` and has much limited use

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов if everything inherits from `Obj` (that in itself is not the best idea imho), then your `Sptr` could simply store a `Obj* obj` and no SFINAE or any conversion needed, because all that `Sptr` needs is an `Obj*` (and pointers to object that derive from `Obj` can already be converted to `Obj*`, nothing extra to be done for that)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Well, nevermind. Anyway, as a novice I've discovered what is SFINAE, thanks.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов don't miss the first comment on this answer. With C++20 things get much less arcane, unfortunately I cannot show you the C++20 way of doing it. Afaik sfinae was only discovered by chance, recent standards got some facilities added to the standard library to support it, but only with concepts in C++20 it made it into the language eventually.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Ok. But, unfortunately, I use C++17.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов I am lucky that I am allowed to use C++11 since last year, but you should keep an eye on what is coming. The language evolved rather quick over the last years and it is good to know what will come